# Entities class constructor renewed with every update of model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

This is not an error but I'm trying to see if there's a workaround for it.
I am using database-first Entity Framework. And my connection string is decided at runtime. So the constructor for my `Entities` class is like this:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities(string cs)
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }
...
}
```

Where `cs` is the connection string. With every small change in my model, when I update it, I would have to add this value to my `Entities` constructor. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're talking about that entire constructor, and you added it: the class is partial, as you can see.

Create a new partial file (`EntitiesPartial.cs` or whatever) that has the same usings and namespace as the existing `Entities.cs` and create the additions there:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities(string cs)
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define another `Partial class` with the same `name` and namespace in sub folder for example

```
  public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities(string cs)
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }
...
}
```

and once done EF will not update your other partial class